# IDEA IntelliJ and code snippet using package and class names

Tags: intellij-idea, code-snippets

I'd like to make quicker a process of creating in every class a piece of code with following definition:

```
private static String TAG = "%PACKAGE_NAME%.%CLASS_NAME%";
```

so the sample result should looking like:

```
package info.chrzanowski.project; // %PACKAGE_NAME%
public class Test { // %CLASS_NAME%

    private static String TAG = "info.chrzanowski.project.Test";

}
```

How can I achieve that with for example using `Alt+Insert` (Generate popup) or in some else way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `Settings | File Templates | Class`, refer to the related documentation sections:

- [File Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-templates.html)
- [Creating and Editing File Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html)
- [File Template Variables](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-template-variables.html)
- [Creating File by Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-file-by-template.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or edit

> Settings | Live templates,

related docs:
[Creating and apllying live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html?search=LIVE%20TEMPLATE#d2216577e156)